# How to convert Image into BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, graphics

Right now I have an image and I want to convert it into a BufferedImage...

This is my code -

```
private BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image img, int width, int height){
    // Create a buffered image with transparency
    BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Draw the image on to the buffered image
    Graphics bGr = bimage.getGraphics();
    bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    bGr.dispose();

    // Return the buffered image
    return bimage;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone explain what's wrong?

Comment: the bimage is null I have no idea why.

Comment: In the code you have posted, it is impossible for `bimage` to be null.  The `new` operator cannot be overridden and cannot return null in Java.  Therefore, if `bimage` is really null, your actual code must be different from what you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

Try the new JRE that includes JavaFX.

You could use SwingFXUtils. There is a method which does what you ask for:

```java
BufferedImage image = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(fxImage, null);
```

or

```java
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
```

Answer (score -1):

BufferedImage extends Image, so you can cast it:

```
BufferedImage buffered = (BufferedImage) image;
```

But you must check the type of your image object in runtime, because it can contain other kind of Image.

**UPDATE**

To convert an Image to a BufferedImage you should check this class and try it:

http://www.dzone.com/snippets/converting-images

Comment: I'm trying to convert the image into a bufferedimage, it is not a bufferedimage originally

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your real problem. I updated my answer.

Comment: I checked it... Still same problem. I get a NullPointerException trying on the drawImage method...